# If $T$ is invertible and $K$ is compact, is $0\ne\lambda\mapsto(\lambda T+K)^{-1}$ holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $T\in\mathfrak L(X)$ be bijective, $K\in\mathfrak L(X)$ be compact and $$B:\mathbb C\to\mathfrak L(X)\;,\;\;\;\lambda\mapsto\lambda T+K.$$

> Can we show that $B(\lambda)$ is bijective for all $\lambda\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ and $$\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}\to\mathfrak L(X)\;,\;\;\;\lambda\mapsto B(\lambda)^{-1}$$ is holomorphic?

This is clearly, if correct, an application of the analytic Fredholm theorem.

The trick is clearly to write $$B(\lambda)=\lambda T\left(1+\frac1\lambda T^{-1}K\right)\tag1\;\;\;\text{for all }\lambda\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}.$$ $\mathbb C\ni\lambda\mapsto\lambda T$ and $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}\ni\lambda\mapsto\frac1\lambda T^{-1}K$ are trivially holomorphic. Moreover, $T^{-1}K$ is compact.

So, the only missing piece is that we need to show that $B(\lambda)$ is bijective for at least one $\lambda\in\mathbb C$. But why is that the case?

Comment: You made no assumptions about $T$ but used its inverse in your argument. If $T=0$ then $B(\lambda)$ is not bijective unless the space is finite dimensional.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Sorry, I've intended to assume that $T$ is bijective.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to assume invertibilty of $T$. In that case $T+\frac 1 n K \to T$ in operator norm. Since the set of all invertble operators is open it folows that $T+\frac 1 n K$ is invertible  for large enough $n$ and this implies that $nT+K$ is invertible for such $n$.

Comment: How do we see that the set of invertible operators is open?

Comment: Almost every book on FA has a proof of this basic result. If $T$ is invertible and $||S-T|| <\frac 1 {2\|T^{-1}\|}$ then $S$ is invertible.  A  proof in the context of Banach algebras  can be found in Thereom 10.11 of Rudin's FA.   @0xbadf00d

Comment: Yes, figured it out. Thank you.

Comment: However, what I wrote in the question is wrong. In order to apply the analytic Fredholm theorem, we don't need to show that $B(\lambda)$ is bijective for at least one $\lambda$; we need to show that $1-\underbrace{\left(1+\frac1\lambda T^{-1}K\right)}_{=:\:A(\lambda)}=-\frac1\lambda T^{-1}K$ is bijective for at least one $\lambda$. How do we see that?

Comment: @0xbadf00d It is impossible for a compact operator on $X$ to be bijective unless $X$ is finite dimensional.